SAP CPI | Message Mapping Json to WSDL
I need to do a message mapping from JSON (Kafka) to SOAP WSDL in SAP CPI.
The built-in message mapping feature from SAP CPI only supports XML/WSDL or Swagger JSON Content.
Is there another way to make the message mapping populate the WSDL?
Is it possible to convert the JSON to an XML and then create a XML for the message mapping?
The JSON I get is also not static in term of content. This means there can be many children like in below JSON.
Do you have a clue how to do the mapping and maybe have an example for that ?
Thank you !
I tried the message mapping through the standard message mapping. But my JSON Response was not accepted. With the WSDL there was no problem.
{
  "item_list": [
            {
                "item_id": "T1",
                "item_text": "Test1"
            },
            {
                "item_id": "T2",
                "item_text": "Test2"
            },
            {
                "item_id": "T3",
                "item_text": "Test3"
                "item_color": "red",
                "item_subtext": "testing"
            },
            {
                "item_id": "T4",
                "item_text": "Test4"
                "item_material": [ 
                    {
                        "item_id": "T4.1",
                        "item_text": "Test4.1",
                        "item_color": "red"
                    },
                    {
                        "item_id": "T4.2",
                        "item_text": "Test4.2",
                        "item_color": "green"
                    }
                ]
            }
           
        ]
    }
}


That's all possible, but I'm unsure what exactly you want to do. For instance, we could also build a REST API where the parameters are extracted from the URL when calling the endpoint, and then filled into the output message using message mapping, with your WSDL as the output message, and then sent as a request to the next system.
Please provide more details so I can give you more targeted answers and help. Describe exactly what you want to accomplish and the scenario.

Hey, thanks for the reply. We have configured a Kafka Sender adapter, which consumes a kafka topic. The messages we get from this topic are in json format. Unfortunately i dont get a Json structure or a Swagger Json from the Kafkaproducer. Now i have the use case, where i need to pass the Json message through to SAP with an SOAP Service. In order to populate the WSDL for the SOAP Service i want to do a Message Mapping from Json to WSDL. But i dont know how to define this message mapping, because SAP CPI only allows XML or Swagger JSON structures.

ok, i understand. What you could do is to transform the incoming json to an xml with the buildin json to xml transformer. With this xml you can do a xsd which you can use as input message for the message mapping.
Check this out : https://help.sap.com/docs/cloud-integration/sap-cloud-integration/define-json-to-xml-converter
Feel free to ask more
